# how to target all textboxes in an application from one trigger and one storyboard

Tags: wpf, triggers

In my following code I have created a trigger and a storyboard for my topmost TextBox. When the mouse enters the topmost TextBox, it turns red and when the mouse enters the rest they don't. 
my question is how can I modify any or both of my mentioned trigger and storyboard so that even if mouse enters the rest TextBoxes, they too turn red like the topmost one.
In my real appliation I have hundreds of textboxes and I don't want to create the mentioned trigger for each separately

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication8"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="textBox">
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
            <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Red"/>
        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter" SourceName="textBox">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" Margin="173.561,97.634,223.439,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Height="23" Margin="173.561,125.634,223.439,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Margin="173.561,153.634,223.439,141.463" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reTemplate your TextBoxBase Style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="120"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>
        <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border 
                          Name="Border"
                          CornerRadius="2" 
                          Padding="2"
                          Background="White"
                          BorderBrush="Black"
                          BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="White"/>
                                        <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="Red"/>
                                    </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox" Height="23" Margin="173.561,97.634,223.439,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" Height="23" Margin="173.561,125.634,223.439,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox2" Margin="173.561,153.634,223.439,141.463" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
</Grid>
```